# How long would it take to crack a message encoded with this Java encryption algorithm?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

I am relatively new to both Java programming and Cryptography and was simply wondering if anyone out there could give me an estimate on how long it would take to de-crypt a message that had been run through this algorithm. (I will definitely not be encrypting anything serious with this)

```
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
static char nchar; // New Character
static String osentence = ""; // The original User Input
static String esentence = ""; // The encrypted User Input
static int iteration = 0; // Iterations
static int inlength = 0;
static Random randomGenerator = new Random();
static int randomInt;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    osentence = sc.nextLine(); // User Input
    inlength = osentence.length();
    while (iteration < inlength) {
        randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3);
        if (randomInt == 0) {
            nchar = encryptm0();
        } else if (randomInt == 1) {
            nchar = encryptm1();
        } else if (randomInt == 2) {
            nchar = encryptm2();
        }
        esentence = esentence + nchar; // Builds the sentence
        iteration++;
    }
    System.out.print(esentence);
}

public static char encryptm0() {
    nchar = osentence.charAt(iteration);
    switch (nchar) {
    case 'a':
        nchar = '☻';
        break;
    case 'b':
        nchar = '◘';
        break;
    case 'c':
        nchar = '♪';
        break;
    case 'd':
        nchar = 'e';
        break;
    case 'e':
        nchar = '↨';
        break;
    case 'f':
        nchar = '☺';
        break;
    case 'g':
        nchar = 'm';
        break;
    case 'h':
        nchar = '▓';
        break;
    case 'i':
        nchar = 'Ë';
        break;
    case 'j':
        nchar = '♥';
        break;
    case 'k':
        nchar = '§';
        break;
    case 'l':
        nchar = 'k';
        break;
    case 'm':
        nchar = '¤';
        break;
    case 'n':
        nchar = '╔';
        break;
    case 'o':
        nchar = '╕';
        break;
    case 'p':
        nchar = 'æ';
        break;
    case 'q':
        nchar = 'q';
        break;
    case 'r':
        nchar = '♫';
        break;
    case 's':
        nchar = 'z';
        break;
    case 't':
        nchar = '◄';
        break;
    case 'u':
        nchar = '►';
        break;
    case 'v':
        nchar = '♠';
        break;
    case 'w':
        nchar = '‼';
        break;
    case 'x':
        nchar = '☼';
        break;
    case 'y':
        nchar = 'Θ';
        break;
    case 'z':
        nchar = '‡';
        break;
    case ' ':
        nchar = '₧';
    case '.':
        nchar = 'a';
    case ',':
        nchar = 'f';
    case ':':
        nchar = 't';
    case ';':
        nchar = 'w';
    }
    return nchar;
}

public static char encryptm1() {
    nchar = osentence.charAt(iteration);
    switch (nchar) {
    case 'a':
        nchar = 'n';
        break;
    case 'b':
        nchar = '■';
        break;
    case 'c':
        nchar = '♕';
        break;
    case 'd':
        nchar = 'p';
        break;
    case 'e':
        nchar = '→';
        break;
    case 'f':
        nchar = 'h';
        break;
    case 'g':
        nchar = '╓';
        break;
    case 'h':
        nchar = '«';
        break;
    case 'i':
        nchar = 'y';
        break;
    case 'j':
        nchar = 'i';
        break;
    case 'k':
        nchar = '‰';
        break;
    case 'l':
        nchar = '*';
        break;
    case 'm':
        nchar = 'r';
        break;
    case 'n':
        nchar = '▬';
        break;
    case 'o':
        nchar = '↔';
        break;
    case 'p':
        nchar = 'v';
        break;
    case 'q':
        nchar = '♂';
        break;
    case 'r':
        nchar = '♀';
        break;
    case 's':
        nchar = '○';
        break;
    case 't':
        nchar = '◙';
        break;
    case 'u':
        nchar = 'c';
        break;
    case 'v':
        nchar = 'b';
        break;
    case 'w':
        nchar = 'º';
        break;
    case 'x':
        nchar = '↓';
        break;
    case 'y':
        nchar = 'x';
        break;
    case 'z':
        nchar = '?';
        break;
    case ' ':
        nchar = '√';
    case '.':
        nchar = '÷';
    case ',':
        nchar = 'ß';
    case ':':
        nchar = '≡';
    case ';':
        nchar = 'í';
    }
    return nchar;
}

public static char encryptm2() {
    nchar = osentence.charAt(iteration);
    switch (nchar) {
    case 'a':
        nchar = '↑';
        break;
    case 'b':
        nchar = '▲';
        break;
    case 'c':
        nchar = 'g';
        break;
    case 'd':
        nchar = 'Š';
        break;
    case 'e':
        nchar = '⌡';
        break;
    case 'f':
        nchar = 'l';
        break;
    case 'g':
        nchar = '♦';
        break;
    case 'h':
        nchar = '←';
        break;
    case 'i':
        nchar = '╠';
        break;
    case 'j':
        nchar = 'Δ';
        break;
    case 'k':
        nchar = 'Ÿ';
        break;
    case 'l':
        nchar = 'o';
        break;
    case 'm':
        nchar = 's';
        break;
    case 'n':
        nchar = 'd';
        break;
    case 'o':
        nchar = '<';
        break;
    case 'p':
        nchar = '∞';
        break;
    case 'q':
        nchar = 'j';
        break;
    case 'r':
        nchar = '¶';
        break;
    case 's':
        nchar = '▼';
        break;
    case 't':
        nchar = '↕';
        break;
    case 'u':
        nchar = '®';
        break;
    case 'v':
        nchar = 'u';
        break;
    case 'w':
        nchar = '$';
        break;
    case 'x':
        nchar = '¬';
        break;
    case 'y':
        nchar = '♣';
        break;
    case 'z':
        nchar = '∟';
        break;
    case ' ':
        nchar = '%';
    case '.':
        nchar = '•';
    case ',':
        nchar = ':';
    case ':':
        nchar = '≈';
    case ';':
        nchar = 'ª';
    }
    return nchar;
}
```

}

Comment: [Not long](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_cipher#Security_for_simple_substitution_ciphers). You have three substitution alphabets; ~150 characters of message.

Answer (score 0):

So this algorithm is basically [security by obscurity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity). The point being it's only "secure" (we'll get back to that in a second) if the attacker doesn't have access to the encryption algorithm. If the attacker does have access, decryption is trivial as he has the mapping back to the original characters.

The cipher you have constructed is a variation of a substitution cipher on which there are many attacks due to the fact that your function is injective or one to one. The fact that you have 3 alphabets adds no security to your algorithm as each character distinctly maps to one of those characters in the target alphabet. So instead of a character mapping to another character you have a character mapping to a set of distinct characters and a random selection of one element from that set, but that reduces to a one to one mapping.

However, if you had something like `a` can map to `b` and `c` can map to `b` that would not be one to one and there would be no distinct decryption.

Finally, the fact that your character mappings are "obscure" characters (ie not a-z for the most part) adds no additional security.

I applaud your interest in crypto and would recommend exploring one time pads and Diffie-Hellman to begin learning about symmetric and asymmetric crypto. In general it is good practice to design your scheme such that it is secure even when everyone (attackers) can know everything about how it works and the only piece you keep secret is a key.

Also, not that your use of `java.util.Random` factored into the security of your algorithm, but `java.util.Random` is not considered cryptographically secure.

Comment: Thanks for your response however, I believe you may have misread the code. The program generates a random number in oder to select a method to use in order to map a symbol to a letter. A new method is re-selected for each character and I believe that this is what you were suggesting I do when you said, "a can map to b and c can map to b". My original question stands as would a message encrypted by this algorithm be hard to crack? Another response would be very welcome as you clearly know more about cryptography than me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Yeah I see the random number is used to select the mapping. The point I was making was that that doesn't actually matter. Why? If you look at the set of all the characters `a` can map to, no other character maps to an element of that set. So, because the mapping is unique per character there is no added security as it reduces to `a` mapping to just one unique character.

For the part about `a` and `c` mapping to `b`. I'm saying your code does not do this, which is good. If it did there would be no distinct decryption. If every character mapped to `b` every message would be a string of `b`s.

Comment: @C.Murphy This cipher is basic enough that it can be broken in at most a few hours, I would expect far less on average.  Other encryption algorithms have been estimated to take a few billion billion years.  **There is a reason why those algorithms are the ones that are in use.**

Comment: This is a few hours by hand. With a computer we're talking seconds due to the nature of simple substitution ciphers

Comment: @C.Murphy If you want to get technical, this approach is called a _polyalphabetic substitution cipher_ and it's mentioned heavily in cryptographic literature: it's been broken numerous times, even before computers. What's even worse, each one of the substitutions uses a completely separate substitution alphabet making it fairly easy through frequency analysis to determine how many substitution alphabets the algorithm uses. This opens up the possibility of attacking each substitution alphabet individually.